# Does $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\ln k}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let $a_k=\dfrac{1}{k\ln k}$

I found out that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for all $n$.

Also,  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$.

So by leibniz alternating series test, I said  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\ln k}$  converges.

Is that true? Does it Absolute converge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, it converges by Leibniz test. However, it does not converge absolutely. (Try the integral test on $\sum |a_k|$.)

Answer (score 1):

It does converge because it is [alternating and elements decrease monotonically to 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). It does not [converges absoluteley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_convergent), see the [condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

I hope this helps ;-)